# How can I run a job on demand in Control-M

Tags: .net, control-m

We would like to run a job in Control-M on demand from an external application without the use of a scheduler.  Is there a Web Service or API that Control-M provides to accomplish this on a .Net application?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few utilities that are supplied with Control-M (command line tools).

These utilities are very helpful in the scenario that you mentioned here. One such utility that we use is 'ctmorder'. We should have a job in Control M database that these utility will be calling. Now depending on the requirement, you can pass the table name / job name / paramaeter to the control M server, and this would trigger the respective job in control M.

Google can give you the path to the utilities documentation of Control-M ("Control-M utility_guide.pdf"). It's not like a plug n play. You will have to work around them a bit to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Java API and a Web Service API, as part of "business process integration". See https://communities.bmc.com/message/482038#482038 and https://communities.bmc.com/community/bmcdn/enterprise_scheduling_workload_automation/blog/2013/11/25/my-control-m-tech-tips-volume-1 for more information.